# Deploying Pool to users (oVirt)

Tags: linux, ovirt

I am starting exploring oVirt (v. 4.3.6) capabilities, so I have created a base-VM, published a Template from it and then deployed a pool of 10 machines based on that Template.

Now, I would like to link users to that Pool. I added a Domain user from Administration->System Permissions->Add, giving him a UserRole permission but when he authenticates in the VM portal, he can see (and run) also the base-VM.

How can I restrict their permissions only to the Pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the Roles are for and which is used for which purpose: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_virtualization/4.0/html/administration_guide/sect-system_permissions#User_Roles_Explained

Then you need to assign the role to the pool resource: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_virtualization/4.2/html/administration_guide/sect-system_permissions#Assigning_an_Administrator_or_User_Role_to_a_Resource

And remove that permission from the base VM of course.

Comment: the user I added with the UserRole role, cannot be removed from the Base-VM. When I click on it in the "Permission" tab of the VM, the "Remove" button is grayed.

Comment: is that the admin user?

Comment: My bad, sorry. I made that user as a "System" user. Thanks